# Unneeded white space before the 1st bar in D3 Stack chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts, stacked-chart

I am trying to populate a data set into D3's Bar chart data. I am using this example from the d3:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768

```
 var causes = ["wounds", "other", "disease"];

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%Y").parse;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.csv",  function(error, crimea) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var layers = d3.layout.stack()(causes.map(function(c) {
        return crimea.map(function(d) {
            return {x: parseDate(d.date), y: +d[c]};
        });
    }));
    var x =  d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain([0,1])
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1, 0);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var z = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");
    console.log(layers);


    x.domain(layers[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]).nice();

    var ticks = x.domain().filter(function(d,i){ return !(i%20); } );
    xAxis.tickValues( ticks );

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
            .data(layers)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "layer")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { return d; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.y0); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis);
});
```

This issue I am getting is that I have some white space which looks ugly. This space come before the 1st bar and also after the last bar of the chart. I have tried tweaking the x value of the bar, But I think that is not a good way to do. [image]

This space does not come when the data set is small. But when dataset is large then this space comes up. How can I remove this space from the start and from end.

JSFiddle For the Above code is
https://jsfiddle.net/7qnngbdc/

Comment: Create a fiddle with some sample data. It will be helpful for us to reproduce the problem and fix.

Comment: JSFiddle For the Above code is https://jsfiddle.net/7qnngbdc/

Comment: @Gilsha jsfiddle added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here --> https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeRoundBands

"Note that rounding necessarily introduces additional outer padding which is, on average, proportional to the length of the domain. For example, for a domain of size 50, an additional 25px of outer padding on either side may be required. Modifying the range extent to be closer to a multiple of the domain length may reduce the additional padding."

After you've set the domain, try this -->

```
    var mult = Math.max (1, Math.floor (width / x.domain().length));
    x.rangeRoundBands ([0, (x.domain().length * mult)], 0.1, 0);
```

Changed in https://jsfiddle.net/7qnngbdc/1/

Comment: After using this logic the width of the xAxis keeps on changing depending on the data can that be fixed @mgraham

Comment: the only way to fit a flexible domain size exactly within a fixed width (range) would be to drop the condition that the bars are integer widths (the 'round' bit) and just use `rangeBands` instead. Some of the bars won't look as crisp then because they are fractional widths with anti-aliasing, but that's about the only drawback (though sometimes if the number of bars is too large and thus too thin, they don't show up at all)